# Google could storage patch is forbidden with http 403 response

Tags: patch, google-cloud-storage, http-status-code-403

I am using a service account to access a cloud storage bucket to add/list/remove file and update meta data. The service account is in the same project and cloud bucket. I set service account as owner for the project team. 
I am using the java API from google

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>${google.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev2-1.18.0-rc</version>


    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-jackson2</artifactId>
        <version>${google.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

With the code, I can add/delete/list/download, but when I update the meta data with patch command, I got a 403 forbidden response,

I go to the cloud storage browser to check permission. All the permissions are listed by cloud storage ID. I can not find out cloud storage ID for my service account. But there is an extra entry as owner besides editor, owner, and team. I assume that it is my service account.

Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: solved: Need StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL permission. Read and Write is not enough to modify meta data

Comment: great to hear you solved your own question! Please write up your comment as an answer and accept it so that this questions is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL permission. Read and Write is not enough to modify meta data. This is not documented anywhere. I found this out in a hard way